# Easy one: "Create Folder" script overwrites its previous entries

Tags: google-apps-script, overwrite, create-directory

I'm a total rookie, so please forgive me if this is a 'duh'.

I've modified a script in order to create a new Gdrive folder for each form that is submitted. The problem is, each time the script runs, it recreates a folder for each row in the spreadsheet. What am I missing?

```
function folderMaker(){
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Form Responses 1');
var last = sheet.getLastRow();//end of roster size

Logger.log('last '+last);
for(var i=2;i<last+1;i++){

var TimeStamp = sheet.getRange(i,1).getValue();//get timestamp code
var eLastName = sheet.getRange(i,39).getValue();//get Employee's Last NameID
var eFirstName = sheet.getRange(i,40).getValue();//get Employee's Last NameID
var eID = sheet.getRange(i,38).getValue();//get Employee's Last NameID
var folder = DriveApp.createFolder(eLastName + ' ' + eFirstName + ' - ' + eID + ' ('+TimeStamp + ')' );
var aFolder = folder.getName();
var aFolderId = folder.getId();
var aFolderUrl = folder.getUrl();
sheet.getRange(i, 82).setValue(aFolder);
sheet.getRange(i, 83).setValue(aFolderId);
sheet.getRange(i, 84).setValue(aFolderUrl);

//Add analyst folders to HRC folder
var HRCFolderID = '[insert form id]'
var HRCFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(HRCFolderID);

var analystFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(aFolderId);

HRCFolder.addFolder(analystFolder);//put analyst folder in HRC folder

DriveApp.getRootFolder().removeFolder(analystFolder);//take analyst folder out of Google Drive
```

Comment: You don't need a `for` loop.  You need to have an "On Form Submit" trigger in your spreadsheet that gets the values of the Form submission, and then creates the folder.  No need to get or loop through all the spreadsheet values.  You can use the `values` property of the event object to get this form submissions values.  [Apps Script Documentation - Event Object - Sheet - On form submit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit)

Comment: Thanks for your response Sandy! Unfortunately, I'm not versed enough to apply what you are referring to here. I have an On Form Submit trigger on this, but I'm not clear what causes the script to loop. This is literally the first time that I've modified a script to this extent.

Comment: Nevermind! I got it! Thanks soooo much.

Comment: You can answer your own question.  If you are going to be a regular user of Stack Overflow, you might want to learn the rules.  [Asking](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0):

After receiving input from Sandy that the `for` command triggers a loop, I removed it and modified the code to focus solely on the last row. Now, in combination with the On Form Submit trigger, each time a form comes in, a folder, along with a URL to the folder, is created. Revised code below:

```
    function folderMaker(){
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Form Responses 1');
    var last = sheet.getLastRow();//end of roster size

Logger.log('last '+last);{

var TimeStamp = sheet.getRange(last,1).getValue();//get timestamp code
var eLastName = sheet.getRange(last,39).getValue();//get Employee's Last NameID
var eFirstName = sheet.getRange(last,40).getValue();//get Employee's Last NameID
var eID = sheet.getRange(last,38).getValue();//get Employee's Last NameID
var folder = DriveApp.createFolder(eLastName + ' ' + eFirstName + ' - ' + eID + ' ('+TimeStamp + ')' );
var aFolder = folder.getName();
var aFolderId = folder.getId();
var aFolderUrl = folder.getUrl();
sheet.getRange(last, 82).setValue(aFolder);
sheet.getRange(last, 83).setValue(aFolderId);
sheet.getRange(last, 84).setValue(aFolderUrl);

//Add analyst folders to HRC folder
var HRCFolderID = '[insert form id]'
var HRCFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(HRCFolderID);

var analystFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(aFolderId);

HRCFolder.addFolder(analystFolder);//put analyst folder in HRC folder

DriveApp.getRootFolder().removeFolder(analystFolder);//take analyst folder out of Google Drive
}

}
```